# How to execute a multi line ATHENA query from Lambda

Tags: lambda

I have Athena set up and I want to schedule a lambda function that triggers the Athena query and stores the results in S3, however, I am getting syntax error in lambda

Response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function'"
}
```

but the same works well in Athena Query editor.

Below is what am trying :

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    query_1 ="Select REGEXP_EXTRACT(data,'[a-z]*[0-9]') as datacenter,
    .
    .
    FROM DATABASE.DATATABLE
    WHERE pool_id like 'POOL_ID%';"

    database = "DATABASE"
    s3_output = "s3://resultlocation/"

    client = boto3.client('athena')

    response = client.start_query_execution(QueryString = query_1,
                                        QueryExecutionContext={
                                            'Database': database
                                        },
                                        ResultConfiguration={
                                            'OutputLocation': s3_output
                                        }
                                        )
    return response
```

When i use a single line query it works fine.

Comment: The AThena hive query is "Select REGEXP_EXTRACT(data,'[a-z]*[0-9]') as datacenter,
                 REGEXP_EXTRACT(response_code,'[0-9]+') CODE,
                 REGEXP_EXTRACT(pool_id,'[a-z]*[0-9]+') as TOWER,"
                 CASE 
                 WHEN response_code like '%2%' THEN '1'
                 WHEN response_code like '%3%' THEN '1'
                 WHEN response_code like '%4%' THEN '1'
                 ELSE '0'
                 END as STATUS
                 FROM DATABASE.DATATABLE
                 WHERE pool_id like 'POOL_ID%';"

Comment: Please update your question with this information rather than posting it in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: I tried, but somehow it didnt let me save it hence i took this approach

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, by adding a "\" at the end of each line.